# How to handle correctly, if the user delete from AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy,

I use TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView to create an outlined spinner.

I don't want to disable the input type, or any other, beacause I would like to use the filter.

So my problem is that, when the user selects an item, in onItemClickListener I save this item into variable, and if the user delets the value from the autoCompleteTextView, the variable still holds the previous selected item.

Off course after that the user shuld have to select an another, but what if not?
So because of this scanario, I want to clear the selectedItem from my variable, but I don't know how to to this correctly?

My first idea was that, I listen the text change, and in the listener I clear my variable. But the problem is, when the user selects an item, this listener also activiate.

Is there a good way to handle this situation?

```
Layout:
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/customer_complaint_recording_data_sheet_partner_label">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/complaint_recording_data_sheet_partner_autocomplete"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

listener:
        binding.complaintRecordingDataSheetPartnerAutocomplete.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            val selected = customerArrayAdapter.getItem(position) as Customer
            if(selected.oid.isNotEmpty())
                viewModel.complaint.value?.customerOid = selected.oid
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, for me, I found the correct way, maybe it will help in the feature.

1, If the user selects on item, I save this in a new variable
2, I check if the autoCompleteTextView text is empty
3, I check that the original ArrayList of items, if it contains the text from autoCompleteTextView
4, Finally, I compare, the original picked item and the item which was found based on the autoCompleteTextView  text

With these validations, the user can not save, if he deletes all the text, or just a part of text